Error converting timestamp to date in Pandas with dt accessor
Here is my example:
import pandas as pd
import datetime
my_df = pd.DataFrame({'date_clmn': [datetime.date(2020, 1, 1),
                                    datetime.date(2020, 2, 1),
                                    datetime.date(2020, 3, 1)]})
my_df['lag_date'] = my_df.date_clmn - pd.DateOffset(months = 3)
my_df.lag_date.dt.date

The last line generates error:
AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

As far as I understand dt accessor should work with timestamps. Why is it producing an error message?
Update
To confirm data type I ran:
my_df.lag_date.apply(type)

It returned:
0    <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timesta...
1    <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timesta...
2    <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timesta...
Name: lag_date, dtype: object


@BigBen, I just posted an update with data type check

datetime.date doesn't produce a column with dtype 'datetime64[ns]'. Use datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1) etc. instead of datetime.date(2020, 1, 1). Or afterwards, on the column: pd.to_datetime(my_df.date_clmn).

I think there is problem dates are converting to datetimes, but in loop, so finally is not created TimeSeries, but objects of Timestamps.
my_df['lag_date'] = my_df.date_clmn - pd.DateOffset(months = 3)
print (my_df.lag_date.apply(type))
0    <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timesta...
1    <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timesta...
2    <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamp

Possible solution is convert datess to datetimes first:
my_df['lag_date'] = pd.to_datetime(my_df.date_clmn) - pd.DateOffset(months = 3)
print (my_df.lag_date.dt.date)
0    2019-10-01
1    2019-11-01
2    2019-12-01
Name: lag_date, dtype: object

Or last:
my_df['lag_date'] = pd.to_datetime(my_df.date_clmn - pd.DateOffset(months = 3))
print (my_df.lag_date)
0   2019-10-01
1   2019-11-01
2   2019-12-01
Name: lag_date, dtype: datetime64[ns]

